# Deleting a dynamically created bootstrap form group with a Jquery onclick event

Tags: html, jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have dynamically created a form-group with an input field and a delete button next to it, this button needs to remove: the button, the div it is contained in and the div that that div is contained in. So essentially the form-group which contains that button.
Here is the PHP code:

```
                            <div class="form-horizontal" id="HighlightForm">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label class="col-sm-4 control-label">
                                        Highlight(s)
                                    </label>
                                    <div id="highlightInput" class="input-group col-sm-8">
                                        <input type="input" name="aHighlight[]" class="form-control" />
                                        <span class="input-group-btn">
                                            <button id="add-highlight" class="form-control add-highlight"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i></button>
                                        </span>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
```

The jQuery portion:

```
$('#add-highlight').on('click', function ()
{
    $('<div class="form-group"><label class="col-sm-4 control-label"></label><div id="highlightInput" class="input-group col-sm-8"> <input type="input" name="aHighlight[]" class="form-control" /><span class="input-group-btn"> <button id="remove-highlight" class="form-control"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></button> </span></div></div>').appendTo('#HighlightForm');
});

$(document).on('click','#remove-highlight', function (e)
{
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).parent('div').parent('div').remove();
});
```

I tried to address the button with $(this) and address the parent div and its parent div to remove the entire form group but that did not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

replace this line solve your issue. Read about [.closest](https://api.jquery.com/closest/)

```
$(this).closest('#highlightInput').remove();
```

```js
$('#add-highlight').on('click', function ()
{
    $('<div class="form-group"><label class="col-sm-4 control-label"></label><div id="highlightInput" class="input-group col-sm-8"> <input type="input" name="aHighlight[]" class="form-control" /><span class="input-group-btn"> <button id="remove-highlight" class="form-control"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></button> </span></div></div>').appendTo('#HighlightForm');
});

$(document).on('click','#remove-highlight', function (e)
{
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).closest('#highlightInput').remove();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-horizontal" id="HighlightForm">
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-sm-4 control-label">
        Highlight(s)
    </label>
    <div id="highlightInput" class="input-group col-sm-8">
        <input type="input" name="aHighlight[]" class="form-control" />
        <span class="input-group-btn">
            <button id="add-highlight" class="form-control add-highlight"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i></button>
        </span>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it should work like this :

```
$('#remove-highlight').click(function(){
    $(_this).parents().remove();
});
```